# Pegar custom category de um custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu criei um custom post type, e uma taxonomia com o plugin CTP UI, porém na hora de listar no loop as categporias que estão marcadas nos posts não são listadas.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'oferta',
        'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );  

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump(get_the_category($post->ID));
        echo "</pre>";
?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**Meu retorno:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Consegui resolver esse problema:

Comment: Consegui resolver esse problema:

`$categoria = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'ofertas_categoria');
var_dump($categoria[0]->name);`

Answer (score 1):

Olá. Eu consegui fazer usando essa formula

```
 <?php
    $taxonomia = "sua taxonomia";
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array(
        "orderby"    => "count",
        "hide_empty" => false,
        ));

    foreach($terms as $term) {
    // faça alguma coisa
    }
```

ou pode adaptar para o enquanto tem post do wordpress.